# Problem while executing command npm run start on scratch LWR projects

Tags: lightning-web-components, node.js, lwc-oss, lightning-web-runtime

I having an issue while running a LWR project.
I am creating a scratch project using the steps shown in https://lwc.dev/ but not able to get proper output (in this case a "Hello World" text) in the web browser.
Can anyone please let me know what step I am missing?

[image]

```
npm init lwr
```

[image]

---X---

```
npm install
```

[image]
---X---

```
npm run start
```

[image]
---X---

```
npm run dev
```

[image]

Adding logs from npm run start script

```
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.18.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle test_project@0.0.1~prestart: test_project@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle test_project@0.0.1~start: test_project@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle test_project@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle test_project@0.0.1~start: PATH: c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\anant\OneDrive\Desktop\test_project\node_modules\.bin;c:\program files\eclipse foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin;c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wbem;c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\windows\system32\openssh\;c:\program files\nvidia corporation\nvidia nvdlisr;c:\msys64\mingw64\bin;c:\program files\git\cmd;c:\program files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\anant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\anant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\anant\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\anant\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\anant\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ffmpeg\bin;C:\adb;C:\apacheMaven\bin
9 verbose lifecycle test_project@0.0.1~start: CWD: C:\Users\anant\OneDrive\Desktop\test_project
10 silly lifecycle test_project@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'MODE=prod node scripts/start-server.mjs' ]
11 silly lifecycle test_project@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 4294967295  signal: null
12 info lifecycle test_project@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: test_project@0.0.1 start: `MODE=prod node scripts/start-server.mjs`
13 verbose stack Exit status 4294967295
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
14 verbose pkgid test_project@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\anant\OneDrive\Desktop\test_project
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
17 verbose argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v14.18.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 4294967295
22 error test_project@0.0.1 start: `MODE=prod node scripts/start-server.mjs`
22 error Exit status 4294967295
23 error Failed at the test_project@0.0.1 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 4294967295, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues/bugs with running on Windows that haven't been addressed yet.  Are you able to run this on a different OS?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/188856)

Comment: Will need to check in Linux, apologies I am looking back to this very late